# How to concat videos and apply filters to one/both of them in one render?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am merging two files but one of them needs hard subtitle applied. I can hardcode once and then concat files but because of codec conflict, it needs encoding two times which I want to avoid because of performance issues.

I have tried to add simple subtitle in filter complex, which I found in [this documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo). Then I tried to apply it on concat video filter example code found on StackOverflow.

```
ffmpeg -i segment.mp4 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] ass=subtitle.ass [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

I have tried to add subtitle only for video.mp4 but then I got:

```
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000002db090dd000] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.4 (SIMPLE)
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000002db090dd000] Using font provider directwrite
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 000002db090dd000] Added subtitle file: 'subtitle.ass' (2 styles, 3 events)
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002db096e6680] Too many inputs specified for the "ass" filter.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

I am not sure If I am just adding filter wrong or it's just wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply subtitles first to the relevant video and then concat the result.

`ffmpeg -i segment.mp4 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]ass=subtitle.ass[v1];[0:v] [0:a] [v1] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv`